# Ошибка:ZeroDivisionError: float modulo

Tags: python

**Задача:** Напишите простой калькулятор, который считывает с пользовательского ввода три строки: первое число, второе число и операцию, после чего применяет операцию к введённым числам ("первое число" "операция" "второе число") и выводит результат на экран.

Поддерживаемые операции: +, -, /, *, mod, pow, div, где
mod — это взятие остатка от деления,
pow — возведение в степень,
div — целочисленное деление.

**Проблема:** При операциях с нулем возвращает:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jailed_code", line 9, in 
print(n1 % n2)
ZeroDivisionError: float modulo

**Мой код:**

```
n1 = float(input())
n2 = float(input()
o = str(input())

if o == 'mod':
    if (n1 or n2) == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(n1%n2)
elif o == 'div':
    if (n1 or n2) == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(n1//n2)  
elif o == '/':
    if (n1 or n2) == 0.0:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:
        print(n1/n2)        
elif o == '*':
    print(n1 * n2)
elif o == '+':
    print(n1 + n2)
elif o == '-':
    print(n1 - n2)
elif o == 'pow':
    print(n1 ** n2)
else:
    print('Something was wrong')
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, если хотите проверить две переменные на 0, то это пишется так:

```
if n1 == 0.0 or n2 == 0.0:
```

В вашем же случае, если, скажем `n1 = 1` и `n2 = 0`, то `(n1 or n2)` получается `(1 or 0)`, что будет равно `1`, и оно никак не будет равно `0`, хотя `n2` при этом "запрещённый" `0`.

А во-вторых, зачем вы делимое проверяете? На ноль же делить нельзя, т.е. только делитель `n2` должен быть не равен 0.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать исключения

```
try:
    #ваш код
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("На ноль делить нельзя")
except:
    print("Ошибка")
```